# driver.switchTo() method not working properly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Below is my `Selenium` code in which I have used the loop for execution but after the first iteration the `switchTo()window()` is not working properly. The control is searching for the element in parent window only. 
Please help me for searching in the same window.

```
for(String Child : d.getWindowHandles())
        {
             d.switchTo().window(Child);
             System.out.println("Title of page is  "+d.getTitle());
        }

        Select dropdown1= new Select(d.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='securityGroup']")));
        dropdown1.selectByVisibleText(e.getCellData("Isin", 5,i));
        // wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("securityGroup"))).sendKeys(e.getCellData("Isin",5 ,i));

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("firstAttribute"))).sendKeys(e.getCellData("Isin",6 ,i));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("secondAttribute"))).sendKeys(e.getCellData("Isin",7 ,i));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("thirdAttribute"))).sendKeys(e.getCellData("Isin",8 ,i));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("fourthAttribute"))).sendKeys(e.getCellData("Isin",9 ,i));
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchButton']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
        d.switchTo().window(parent);
        System.out.println("Title of page is  "+d.getTitle());
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='openGenerateFISN();' and @title='Generate']"))).click(); 
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
         for(String Child1 : d.getWindowHandles())
        {
             d.switchTo().window(Child1);
            System.out.println("Title of page is  "+d.getTitle());
        }

        if(!(e.getCellData("Isin", 10, i).isEmpty()))`enter code here`
        {
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to search for the element both in the parent window and the actual window?

Comment: Which line of code opens the new _TAB_? What are you trying to do in `d.switchTo().window(parent);`?

Comment: is there more than one windows handle in `d.getWindowHandles()`? if not, you don't have any windows, maybe you have something else (popup?)